# Android scaling dimensions of included view

Tags: android, layout

I have a view where I defined sizes using dip.

I want to include this in other layouts in different sizes. I thought setting the size in the include tag

```
<include
   android:id="@+id/abc"
   android:layout_width="100dip"
   android:layout_height="100dip"
   layout="@layout/myInclude" 
 />
```

would make that my included layout is resized proportionally but it doesn't. So everything I defined using dip in the included layout appears with the same size and breaks the layout.

Is this expected behaviour and what can I do to solve this?

A possible solution in to use LinearLayout with weights in the included layout, instead of hardcode in dip. But with dip I have more control, and don't have to use LinearLayouts everywhere...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you specify a size in dip or any other fixed unit, it won't resize automatically. That would be weird, generally when you hardcode a size you don't want your view to be resized.

Layout weights (and LinearLayouts) are the only way to go.

Comment: Resize hardcoded image makes sense for me, because I want to have it hardcoded inside a certain view, but if I include it in other with a different size, I would like to have the option to resize it. Like bitmaps, they have a fixed size themselves, but you can resize them.

Comment: Now the problem of using weights is that for example I can't define padding and margins proportionally. I have to set them in dip. So my include will scale according to weights but the margins and padding are still fixed so it will not be proportional. And I get also other problems using weights, like how do I make that the contained images are resized but still mantain square shape and don't become rectangles...

Comment: So you should think about creating a custom view, which is the recommended way to go when it seems tricky to do what you want with the built-in android layouts. This way you can resize your image (and margins) programatically.

Comment: I will think about it. It's something I will use only from 3 places in the app and is always almost equal, besides it has to be resized... I don't know if it's worth creating a custom view for that... maybe I just copy my XML 3 times and modify it.